# Trace loss in LTTng

Tags: lttng

I am using Lttng in an application. I have enabled heavy traces and I have found that there is a loss in traces.  Is there any way of knowing if there is any trace loss or any information regarding about it . Are there any API calls to know about them.

Thanks & Regards.,
K.V.Ranganadh.

Comment: Have you searched the documentation?

Comment: Yes, I have searched the documentation http://lttng.org/docs/ here , but I could not find any

Comment: I am having this problem when my cpu is of high load and lot of traces were enabled . so , to know the traces I have missed I could not find any documentation regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

Both [viewers](http://lttng.org/viewers/) for LTTng traces should both be able to report if a trace has lost events in them.

Babeltrace, the command-line trace reading tool, prints lost events on stderr. So a quick way to locate these is to reroute stdout elsewhere, so you only see the lost events in the console, using a command like:

```
babeltrace /path/to/trace > /dev/null
```

Alternatively, the graphical viewer Trace Compass displays lost events in its Statistics View.

In general, lost events happen when the machine is too loaded and the tracer cannot keep up with the events coming in. To reduce the chance of losing events, you can look at increasing the subbuffer sizes and number (see the 'lttng' man page), or enabling less events in your tracing session (instead of doing 'lttng enable-event ... -a', only enable the events you need).